# How to make ERC20 smart contracts ask for ether as transaction fee using Remix

Tags: transactions, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

please am a newbie in solidity I have been trying  to make the transfer not to work if the wallet holding the token does not transfer ether to an address i will specify in my code thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Smart contract cannot ask users to get tokens or eth, you should program your DApp or Front End for asking transaction fee.
2. you can set something like *require(msg.value==transactionFee)* followed by *payable(AddressToCollectFees).transfer(msg.value)* in the function of smart contract

Comment: So i should build a DApp to control my token